# Representing a word as sequence of bits

Tags: python

I want to represent a word as a sequence of 26 bits. If 25th bit is set it means that the letter 'y' is present in that word.

For example: word:"abekz"
             representation:10000000000000010000010011
This is very easy to do it in C/C++ since it has a 32 bit int type. But Python's int has infinite precision so I'm unable to do it.

Here's my (Wrong)solution:

```
def representAsBits(string):
  mask=0
  for each_char in string:
    bit_position= ord(each_char)-97 #string consists of only lower-case letters
    mask= mask | (1<<bit_position)
  return bin(mask)

print representAsBits("abze")# gives me 0b10000000000000000000010011
print representAsBits("wxcc")# gives me 0b110000000000000000000100  2 bits missing here
```

What changes can I make? Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is correct, the 2 "missing bits" are just the leading `0`s, so it's not showing you them. `"a"` yields `0b1`. If you want to print the whole thing, you'll have to pad it out with the leading zeroes.

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to be done automatically, instead of patching Zeroes manually. Is there any way to get 32 bit int in Python?

Comment: The int isn't what the problem is, you want it to **display** in a certain way. This method works and generates proper integers with the appropriate bits set. the bits aren't shown because they are leading bits. `0b0000000001 == 0b1` is `True`, because it is the same number.

Comment: My goal is to find whether two words have are distinct or not, After ANDing two words together ,If any bit is 1 that means  both the words have the same letter occurring in them.. How will I know how many zeroes to pad and where to pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store leading zeroes on an integer. Thankfully, you're using `bin()`, which returns a string.

With a little creative slicing, we can format it however we want:

```
return "0b%32d" % int(bin(mask)[2:])
```

will give:

```
>>> representAsBits("abekz")
'0b00000010000000000000010000010011'
```

That being said, to compare masks, you **don't have to `bin()` them** except if you want to "show" the binary. Compare the integers themselves, which will be the same:

with `return mask`:

```
>>> representAsBits("z") == representAsBits("zzz")
True
```

Although, since the masks will match, it **doesn't matter what padding you use**, as they will be the same if generated from the same mask: Any string containing only the characters `wxc` will yield the same string, regardless of what method you use.

Comment: Okay, So If I compare a 26 bit mask with a 24 bit mask will python automatically pad the 24 bit with two extra zeros while Anding them together? My eventual goal is to just AND them to check for common letters.

Comment: there aren't "26 bit mask"s or "24 bit mask"s. There are just integers you're interpreting a particular way. Python will properly bitwise and(`&`) integers: `0b11111 & 0b101` yields `5`, which is `0b101`

Comment: Also, checking for distinctness you may want to do a [bitwise xor (`^`)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) which will yield `0` **only when they match**.